# Show that there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $$\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)dt=f(x)$$ holds for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$. Show that there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

$\textbf{My solution:}$ It is given that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)dt \hspace{0.5cm}...(1)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

This also implies that $$2y.f(x)=\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)dt \hspace{0.5cm}...(2)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x$ (by Leibnitz Rule), we have $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2y}\left(f(x+y)-f(x-y)\right)$$ $$\implies 2y.f'(x)=f(x+y)-f(x-y)\hspace{0.5cm}...(3)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $y$ (by Leibnitz Rule), we have $$2f(x)=f(x+y)+f(x-y)\hspace{0.5 cm}...(4)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Adding $(3)$ and $(4)$ and dividing both sides of the equality by $2$ we have $$f(x)+yf'(x)=f(x+y)$$ $$\implies f'(x)=\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}\hspace{0.5cm}...(5)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Again differentiating $(3)$ with respect to $x$ we have $$2y.f''(x)=f'(x+y)-f'(x+y)\hspace{0.5cm}...(6)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Now, by differentiating $(3)$ with respect to $y$ we have $$2f'(x)=f'(x+y)+f'(x-y)\hspace{0.5cm}...(7)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Adding $(5)$ and $(6)$ and dividing both sides of the equality by $2$ we have $$f'(x)+yf''(x)=f'(x+y)$$ $$\implies f''(x)=\frac{f'(x+y)-f'(x)}{y}\hspace{0.5cm}...(8)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Now let us take any $x=x_1\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by $(5)$ we have $$f'(x_1)=\frac{f(x_1+y)-f(x_1)}{y}, \forall y>0.$$

Now let us take any $y=y_1>0$. Then by applying MVT to the function $f$ on the interval $[x_1,x_1+y_1]$ we can conclude that $\exists c_1\in(x_1,x_1+y_1)$ such that $$f'(c_1)=\frac{f(x_1+y_1)-f(x_1)}{y_1}$$ $$\implies f'(x_1)=f'(c_1).$$

Again by applying MVT to the function $f'$ on the interval $[c_1,x_1]$ we can conclude that $\exists c_2\in(c_1,x_1)$ such that $$f''(c_2)=\frac{f'(x_1)-f'(c_1)}{x_1-c_1}=0$$ $$\implies f''(c_2)=0.$$

This implies by $(8)$ we can conclude that $f'(c_2)=f'(c_2+y), \forall y>0$.

Now by $(7)$ we have $$2f'(c_2)=2f'(c_2+y)=f'(c_2+y)+f'(c_2-y)$$ $$\implies f'(c_2+y)=f'(c_2-y)$$ $$\implies f'(c_2-y)=f"(c_2+y)=f'(c_2), \forall y>0.$$

Thus we have $f'(x)=f'(c_2)=c, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Thus we can conclude that $f$ is linear, which implies that, $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is there a better and shorter solution to this problem?

Comment: We only require that $f$ be continuous here.  I would instead write $2yf(x)=\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)dt$ and differentiate this equation w.r.t. $y$ to get $$2f(x)=f(x+y)+f(x-y).$$  From this result, you can show that $$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$ if $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$.  This is Cauchy's functional equation.  Continuity of $f$ implies continuity of $g$, therefore $g(x)=ax$ for some constant $a$.  If $b=f(0)$, then $f(x)=ax+b$ as required.

Comment: @SanketBiswas Check the sign when you differentiate (2) with respect to $x$.

Comment: @PierreCarre, my bad, I wrote the limits wrong. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: @SanketBiswas Maybe I would cut it shorter after (5). Using Taylor's theorem you get $$f(x+y)=f(x)+yf'(x) + \frac 12 y^2 f''(\xi), \quad \xi \in (x,x+y),$$ from where you can establish that $f'' = 0$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258268/42969.